# MVC Removing ApplicationCookie from Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

In previous MVC projects using forms authentication i was able to strip the authentication cookie from the response using an action filter with the following override.

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
}
```

I have now switched over to use OWIN based asp.net identity 2.0 and in the same way I would like to remove their version of the authentication cookie.

I have modified the filter (below) to use the new cookie name but the cookie is no longer being removed.

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    const string authenticationCookie = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(authenticationCookie);
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Strange desires. Do you just want to change the cookie name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the authentication occurs in the OWIN pipeline with it's own environment dictionary, whereas your previous FormsAuthentication was using System.Web.HttpContext.

If you set a breakpoint on :

```
 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies
```

and view the variable you will see it doesn't even have a cookie named `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` so you're not removing anything.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by removing the cookie rather than just logging the user out but a way to do something similar would be to create an action filter as below:

```
public class CookieStripperAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
        filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Environment.Add("StripAspCookie", true);
    }
}
```

Apply that as necessary and then do a check for the action prior to OWIN writing out the message headers by creating some OWIN middleware

```
  public class AuthenticationMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
        {
            const string _authenticationCookie = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie;

            public AuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) :
                base(next) { }

            public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
                {
                    var resp = (OwinResponse)state;

                    if (resp.Environment.ContainsKey("StripAspCookie"))
                    {
                        resp.Cookies.Delete(_authenticationCookie);
                    }
                }, response);

                await Next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
```

You would attach that middleware in your startup class:

```
 app.Use(typeof(AuthenticationMiddleware));
```

Note though that while this will eat the cookie it wont log the user out but as I say I'm not sure if that is your intention anyway.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was wanting to remove the cookie rather than log the user out is because i have an asynchronous request running on a timer checking whether the user is still logged in or not. By not removing the cookie and having sliding expiration set to 'on' this will have the effect of keeping the session alive longer than what I want.

Comment: In the meantime I was also able to accomplish this by removing the cookie from Application_EndRequest in global.asax.

Comment: Hi, For me, I can't get this to work as the response cookie collection is always empty in my case. I have exactly similar requirements as yours. I want to log off the user if there is an auto refresh!